# Do I need to create a failed jobs table when using Redis as queue driver in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis, queue

I'm using `redis` as the queue driver for Laravel 5.2. My problem is when a job fails, I get an exception in laravel.log which says `PDO` couldn't find the `failed_jobs` table.

I know I can use `artisan` to create the migration for creating failed jobs table, but do I need to do this when I'm running the queue on redis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**, you don't have to. Failed jobs are handled by [`DatabaseFailedJobProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Queue/Failed/DatabaseFailedJobProvider.php), which implements [`FailedJobProviderInterface`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Queue/Failed/FailedJobProviderInterface.php). You can implement this interface yourself with the backend of your choice. You also need to extend [`QueueServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a38acf7ee2882d831a3b9a1361a710e70ffa31e/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueServiceProvider.php) and replace the [`registerFailedJobServices()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a38acf7ee2882d831a3b9a1361a710e70ffa31e/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueServiceProvider.php#L234-L250) method with your implementation of `FailedJobProviderInterface`:

```
/**
 * Register the failed job services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function registerFailedJobServices()
{
    $this->app->singleton('queue.failer', function ($app) {
        // Your implementation here.
    });
}
```